# complexity of query.find()

Tags: parse-platform, complexity-theory, parse-server

Is it computationally expensive to run query.find() in parse-server to fetch data.

If yes, Is there a better solution available that can be used to fetch data in real time?

Comment: I think an approximate answer can be had by reviewing the costs of mongdb find.  The more practical question is your second one: are there alternatives?  Not while remaining in parse-server.

Comment: But using indexing on the field, can't one reduce the commplexity to O(logn) ?